# Why don't PyCrypto and OpenSSL produce the same output using Blowfish ECB?

Tags: openssl

As explained in [this thread](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/24050/why-dont-pycrypto-and-m2crypto-produce-the-same-result-as-openssl-here-aes-128), PyCrypto and OpenSSL produce the same output using AES ECB, assuming you skip the key derivation function with the -K option for OpenSSL. I tested it and got the same output.

However, when I use Blowfish ECB I get completely different output. This code:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import Blowfish
key = 'secret'
plaintext = 'abcdefgh'
cipher = Blowfish.new(key, Blowfish.MODE_ECB)
ciphertext = cipher.encrypt(plaintext)
print ciphertext.encode('hex')
```

Produces the output:

```
03582d2666553c05
```

These commands:

```
key=$(printf 'secret' | od -tx1 -An -v | tr -d ' ')
printf 'abcdefgh' | openssl enc -bf-ecb -nopad -K "$key" | od -tx1 -An -v | tr -d ' '
```

Produce the output:

```
166ac1ff98632178
```

Why is it different for the Blowfish cipher?

EDIT:

I did some reading and [this thread](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/19687/blowfish-ecb-with-openssl-doesnt-give-the-expected-result) has the answer, I think. OpenSSL is zero-padding the key to 128 bits. See what happens when you change

```
key = 'secret'
```

to

```
key = 'secret1234567890'
```

Is there any way around this - I don't see anything in the OpenSSL manual? Is there another commandline program that doesn't zero-pad the key?

Comment: I'm afraid this isn't correct SE for this question. You should consult OpenSSL mailing-lists, forums, documentation etc., maybe stackoverflow or security SE.